# UIScrollView selected cell goes out of present view on rotation to landscape

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UITableView in a UIScrollView. The tables cells are vertical, i.e. one below the other. If I select the bottom cell, in portrait, it highlights and displays a popover. However, on rotating to landscape, the selected cell goes out of the visible view, but its popover remains. I understand that UIScrollView on rotate uses the top most cell from the UITableView as the topmost in the new (Landscape) orientation. How do I force it to still keep the selected cell in the view on rotation, i.e. on rotation, possibly rotate with the selected cell as the point of reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to call this method in your interface rotation event of view controller.

```
-(void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
             atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
                     animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Here is what you can do in your view controller:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromOrientation
{
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

You can get the indexPath of selected row from the following event:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure war scrollToRowAtIndex does, and never tried. I had the indexPath to check if the selected cell is visible.